# Powershell Copying CDATA

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I'm looking for a solution to allow copying of CDATA between XML Files?

- I open two XML files (oldfile.xml & newfile.xml)
- For each name in oldfile.xml, update it with the values in newfile.xml
- Save the update to oldfile.upd.xml.

In the script below, everything works fine, until attempting to copy a value containing CDATA.

It fails with the error:

- *Cannot set "value" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties*

Contents of OldFile.xml:

```
<configuration>
        <mainsect>
                <subsect>
                        <setting name="Microsoft" retype="String">
                                <value>www.microsoft.com/old</value>
                        </setting>
                        <setting name="Apple" retype="String">
                                <value>www.apple.com/old</value>
                        </setting>
                        <setting name="Yahoo" retype="String">
                                <value>www.yahoo.com/older</value>
                        </setting>
                        <setting name="IBM" retype="String">
                <value><![CDATA[https://www.ibm.net/old/mycontainer?sv=2020-03-28%3D]]></value>
                        </setting>
                </subsect>
        </mainsect>
</configuration>
```

Contents of NewFile.xml

```
<configuration>
    <mainsect>
        <subsect>
            <setting name="Microsoft" retype="String">
                <value>https://www.microsoft.com/new</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Apple" retype="String">
                <value>https://www.apple.com/new</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="IBM" retype="String">
                <value><![CDATA[https://www.ibm.net/new/mycontainer?sv=2018-03-28%3D]]></value>
            </setting>
        </subsect>
    </mainsect>
</configuration>
```

The script:

```
[XML] $oldObj = Get-Content "C:\temp\example\oldfile.xml"
[XML] $newObj = Get-Content "C:\temp\example\newfile.xml"

# ... Update old values with new values .....

$oldObj.configuration.mainsect.subsect.setting | % {

    foreach($elem in $newObj.configuration.mainsect.subsect.setting)
        {
        if ($_.Name -eq $elem.Name)  # found matching names, replace values
            {
            echo ("Updating {0}" -f $_.Name)

            $_.retype  = $elem.retype
            $_.value   = $elem.value   # !! Throws when hits CDATA in IBM !!

            break;
            }
        }
    }

$oldObj.Save("C:\temp\example\oldfile.upd.xml")
```

I tried using $_.value.InnerText and couldn't get ReplaceChild() to work correctly, but that could just be my inexperience.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doing this with `XML` (which is `XmlDocument` under the covers) is involved, since you have to actually clone nodes. The API is not the friendliest. For editing purposes I recommend using `XElement` instead (from `System.Xml.Linq`), which isn't as transparent (you need `.GetElements("section")` instead of having a `section` property, for example) but can copy elements without trouble (`$new.Add($old.Element("value"))`).

Comment: Jeron, Thanks for the help.  However, I am reluctant to retool at this point, unless there are no other options.  Is there anyway I can make the above work?  Can you see any way of making the current XML objects work with CDATA?

Comment: Would the answer change if the whole entry can be removed and re-add?

Comment: It's hard to give working code because your XML snippet doesn't match your processing code. If you want to try your hand at a [mre] specifying input and output, that would be nice. Otherwise, take a look at [`ImportNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode); this and some combination of `RemoveAll`/`RemoveChild`/`ReplaceChild` would likely solve your problem.

Comment: `$_.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerXml = $elem.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerXml` should do it. This just replaces the whole markup of `value`, CDATA and all. It will leave nodes other than `value` (if there are any, there aren't in this example) alone. (It will not work if there is no `value` node in the original, however; dealing with that situation really is more complicated.)

Comment: It works :-)  Thank you!